# How to embed HTML page in a resizeable way?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to embed a page developed by me using AngularJS into another third-party page (that may/may not be using AngularJS). To the third party it should be just as simple as adding a small piece of code - just like what they do to embed tweets from Twitter or add a comment box from Facebook.

I tried using `<iframe>`, but when my page is larger than iframe's size, scroll bars appear which I don't want. How to embed my page so that scroll bars don't appear and it appears that the embedded page is part of the original third-party website?

The embeddable page contains something similar to tweets/Fb comment box.

PS: Assume I have no control over the third-party sites.

PPS (to avoid the confusion): I control the content of the embeddable page i.e. I have control over what's there inside the `iframe`. But I don't have any control over the page where this `iframe` will be put. I need a piece of code (JS/html) which can be given to others so that after they add this piece of code, they will have my content in their page.

Comment: The wording is confusing to me. Do you control the content of the `iframe` or not?

Comment: I control the content of ```iframe```. But I don't have control over the page where ```iframe``` is put. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question

Comment: Perhaps you could do a small javascript snippet that the third party includes with the id of a div or other container that your javascript can then embed it's own iframe into? With that you may have more control over the iframe itself.

Comment: To me it sounds like your page needs a responsive layout. See how when you [resize the iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/8ydfo2yv/) that the content adjusts itself based on the height/width of the iframe.

Comment: My previous comment is how most of the other content providers accomplish that very same task, including twitter.

Comment: @TheGunner : Can you post what you suggested as an answer? Also can you give an example of the JS snippet which embeds the content from content provider? I am a back-end dev and am a novice when it comes to front-end stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheGunner for pointing me in the right direction. But he didn't specify the resizing part. So if the embedded page is bigger than the `iframe` then scroll bars would appear. To prevent this, you can call `window.PostMessage` from the embeddable page and the listener will take care of the resizing part.

I have created a script which assigns dynamic `id` to the `iframe`, and this `id` is used later to resize.(My script takes care only the height of the `iframe`. If the embeddable page is responsive, width shouldn't be a problem).

Here is the content of `widget.js` (this contains the `window.PostMessage` listener and the code to create `iframe`):

```
(function() {
var func = function(e){
    if (e.data.indexOf('iid:') === 0) {
        var hashPos = e.data.indexOf('#');
        var iid = e.data.substring('iid:'.length, hashPos);
        var height = e.data.substring(hashPos + 1) + 'px';
        document.getElementById(iid).style.height = height;
    }
};
var old = window.onmessage;
if (typeof window.onmessage != 'function') {
    window.onmessage = func;
} else {
    window.onmessage = function (e, f, g, h) {
        if (old) {
            old(e, f, g, h);
        }
        func(e);
    };
}
}());
var BuildWidget = function(url, width) {
    var getNewIid = function() {
        return 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    };

    var iid = getNewIid();
    if(!width) {
        width = 900;
    }
    var maxWidth = width + 'px';
    document.write('<iframe id="' + iid + '" src="' + url + '?iid=' + iid + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="min-width: 300px; width:100%; max-width:' + maxWidth + '; display:block;"></iframe>');
};

var AddXWidget = function(width) {
     var url = 'http://localhost:8080/embed';
     BuildWidget(url, width);
};
```

Now give out the following script to third-party sites to enable them to embed your widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://path/to/widget.js">
</script>
<script>
     AddXWidget(400);
</script>
```

Now, the embeddable page(the page inside `iframe`) should call `window.PostMessage()` as follows:

```
window.top.postMessage('iid:' + iid + '#' + elem.scrollHeight, '*');
```

Here `iid` is the URL parameter `iid` obtained and `elem` is the element looked up using `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example, all credit goes to giveforward.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.giveforward.com/widget.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    BuildWidget('c8c3');
</script>
```

the included javascript file simply defines a couple of functions and writes it's own `iframe` to the page.

```
function BuildWidget(fid)
{
  makeFrame(fid);
}

function makeFrame(fid) 
{
   document.write('<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.giveforward.com/widgets/w/'+fid+'/?m=1" style="min-width: 240px; width:100%; max-width:295px; height: 450px;margin:auto;display:block;"></iframe>');
}

function BuildAffiliateWidget(affid, packet) {
  if(typeof packet == 'object')
  {
    refid = (typeof packet.refid == 'undefined') ? '' : '&refid=' + packet.refid;
    category = (typeof packet.category == 'undefined') ? '' : '&category=' + packet.category;
    title = (typeof packet.title == 'undefined') ? '' : '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(packet.title);
    callback = (typeof packet.callback == 'undefined') ? '' : '&callback=' + packet.callback;
    gfid = (typeof packet.gfid == 'undefined') ? '' : '&gfid=' + packet.gfid;
  }else
  {
    refid = title = category = callback = gfid = '';
  }
  document.write('<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.giveforward.com/widgets/a/?m=1&affid=' + affid + refid + category + title + callback + gfid + '" style="min-width: 240px; width: 100%; max-width:295px; height:450px;margin:auto;display:block;" class="affiliate_iframe"></iframe>');
}
```

The url that the iframe points to can be the same url that you are having your users embed to their own iframe now.

Comment: Thanks @TheGunner for pointing me in the right direction. But your answer doesn't specify the resizing part and it contains code specific to that website. I have created a script which should be generic. Posting it as an answer. Thanks for your input. Cheers!